# correct usage with paragraphs

Tags: american-english, british-english

The next car to test was the Dodge Challenger. This vehicle was excellent to drive, and it had great handling. However, the interior was dated, and it had cosmetic faults, but these could be rectified later, and weren't necessarily a divisive factor in the cars value as a whole. *The vehicle was famously used in the film 'Vanishing Point' in 1971, as a result this model has nostalgic value to fans of the film, and 1970's culture.*

I wasn't sure if the last sentence should start a new paragraph, and when would we use a one sentence paragraph in general?

Also the paragraph as a whole is suggested to have many punctuation errors: I can't see any.

Answer (score 1):

The next car to test was the Dodge Challenger. This vehicle was excellent to drive, and it had great handling. However, the interior was dated, and it had cosmetic faults, but these could be rectified later, and weren't necessarily a divisive factor in the **car's** value as a whole. The vehicle was famously used in the film 'Vanishing Point' in **1971;** as a **result,** this model has nostalgic value to fans of the film, and **1970s** culture.

The last sentence (or you could split it into two sentences) might or might not form a separate paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

When to start a new paragraph is a largely stylistic consideration, though in any given academic situation there are likely to be certain expectations, and when writing for publication expectations will be set by editors (or by general industry standards).

I wouldn't start a new paragraph there, personally, because it's not a new subject or point, but you need to be consistent between different parts of the same piece of writing. There are overall judgements people will make based on starting a new paragraph too readily, or too reluctantly; the most important thing, however, is that you do so consistently.

As to grammatical errors, I'm not sure I see any out-and-out errors, apart from a comma that should be a full stop (or semicolon), or followed by an appropriate conjunction (*as* is only a conjunction when used in certain ways), in the italicised sentence. There's also a ludicrous number of commas in the third sentence. You want to break that sentence up.

Comment: There are a lot of commas in that sentence, but I think that's poor style rather than an actual error. "divisive" might be a typo for "decisive".